# Set method(?) in Python

Tags: python

I am taking the course "Machine Learning with the Experts: School Budgets" at Data Camp and there is one part in the exercise I don't understand. I was unable to find anything on the Internet on it.

```
def combine_text_columns(data_frame, to_drop=NUMERIC_COLUMNS + LABELS):
    """ converts all text in each row of data_frame to single vector """

    # Drop non-text columns that are in the df
    to_drop = set(to_drop) & set(data_frame.columns.tolist())
    text_data = data_frame.drop(to_drop, axis=1)
```

I don't understand the line `set(to_drop) & set(data_frame.columns.tolist())`, "set" in particular. What function does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic
>   uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set
>   objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection,
>   difference, and symmetric difference.
>
> **Curly braces or the set() function can be used to create sets**

You are creating a set when you do `set(to_drop) & set(data_frame.columns.tolist())`

---

In sets, `&` performs **Intersection** i.e.

> The resulting set has elements that are common to both source sets. An
>   element is in the result if it is in one set and the other.

Example:

```
>>> fib = set((1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13))
>>> prime = set((2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13))
>>> fib & prime  
    set([2, 3, 5, 13])
```

Answer (score 0):

A Set is an unordered collection data type that has no duplicate elements.

`set(to_drop)` selects unique values from `to_drop`.

`set(data_frame.columns.tolist())` selects unique values from the list `data_frame.columns.tolist()`

The `&` operator perform the intersection of both the sets (just like in mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. Yes, it is a basic function, it has been less than one month since I got my hands on Python. I hope next time I won't raise such silly questions.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Yes ) I just wanted to thank for the comments on my question.I already market the answer by Agile as a correct answer.